# How does a Google Nest power connector work?

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I am looking at the [installation instructions](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/WJrWiEaeDuoZnn7t6LNYcRa50GQKt4dECMKH) and they all show that the power connector goes back to the furnace/AC control panelIf this is installed just to make sure the thermostat gets enough power to recharge and properly connect to wifi why do I need to go back to furnace for this???

For power only I could use power outlet near the thermostat. In my case I have the furnace/ac in the basement and the thermostat on the main floor. So there is no C wire running between the two floors. From the picture below (my case) I am seeing the adapter interjected between the furnace/AC and the thermostat BUT I do not see what that is adding for the thermostat since the same RWY wires will go back to the thermostat.
[image]
Are they saying that there is not enough amperage on the RY wires to charge/power up the Nest Thermostat and this is what the power adapter does ?
More about my particular wiring here
[Why can't my Trane/Honeywell thermostat be replaced with a Google Nest non learning thermostat?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/287689/why-cant-my-trane-honeywell-thermostat-be-replaced-with-a-google-nest-non-learn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power connector changed the protocol between the furnace and the thermostat.

The regular protocol is simply shorting R with either W or Y for heating/cooling. This traditionally closes a circuit through a relay that then activates the heating and cooling. However a relay designed to be pulled in for an extended period of time only lets through a few milliamps and requires a certain voltage to be across its own coil. This means that the thermostat only has (delivered voltage - minimal voltage)*(current through coil) power to leach power from in ideal circumstances. More advanced furnaces might be using electronics to sense the short between R and the heating/cooling wire, which means even less current needs to flow and even less power can leached. There is also almost no way for a thermostat to differentiate between these furnaces

The power connector instead uses the thermostat-side R and W/Y wires as a dual power/communication line and uses either powerline ethernet or wifi (or something else entirely) to communicate whether the power connector should short its furnace-side R and W/Y.

The thermostat R will likely be connected straight through so that shorting that with another furnace-side signal wire (for example the W in a heating/cooling furnace) will work properly.

Comment: Your explaination is pretty much what I assumed it is happening but you seem to be wrong in regards to the W line. As you see in the picture it is still connected straight to the furnace. Do you have any references for this?

Comment: I referred to the non-R wire as W/Y because when it us used for heating only that's the wire being connected.